# How to identify the reciever email is incorrect while sending multiple emails

Tags: python, email, ssl, smtplib

I have written a code to send multiple emails using python (using smtplib, ssl modules). I have CSV file from where i read the emails and send the message one by one. Now my query is:
If by chance one or more emails are entered incorrectly(inside the CSV File) then is there any way that i can get the **message** in my **console** that **the message has not been sent because of the incorrect email**.

Comment: It's called an `error log` — check there.

Comment: I'L'l Can you please elaborate about it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "one or more emails are entered incorrectly?"  If you mean that the email address isn't the one you **wanted**, but it is still otherwise a valid (or at least valid-looking) address, there's no way for the code to know that.

Comment: @MananjotSingh: Generally if you are sending emails to an address that does not exist it is logged as an error in your mail log; this is what you want to observe to determine the invalid email addresses.

Comment: @John its like invalid email (but valid looking) like a email 'abc@gmail.com' but incorrectly stored as 'ab@gmail.com' which is invalid(no such address exist). For such a case we get email at the senders address as "Address not found" from mail delivery subsystem. is there any way to show this on console?

Comment: @l'L'l It's my understanding that if the _host_ exists but the _username_ does not, you will generally not receive any sort of error, due to anti-spam measures.

Comment: @JohnGordon: If an email address doesn't exist, or is not able to receive email for whatever reason most mail servers will respond with a [`550 error`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMTP_server_return_codes#5xx_Permanent_errors) (at least they are supposed to) . As you mentioned, depending on the mail server it's possible it might not respond with anything for spam protection reasons, although circumventing an error response isn't really the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is not trivial. Delivery errors due to an invalid recipient address can happen at multiple stages of the delivery:

The simplest case is when the delivery fails already within the SMTP dialog. In this case one could simply check the status of the SMTP `RCPT TO` command which is reflected in the [SMTPRecipientsRefused](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused) exception. But this will at most happen if you communicate with the SMTP server responsible  for the recipients domain.

For later delivery errors the final SMTP server running into the problem will generate a bounce mail with a delivery status notification. To get these you need to make sure that you specify a SMTP sender you control and which actually can receive these bounce mails so that you are able to collect these delivery status problems, parse these and extract which target address failed.

This is not trivial either since these delivery status mails can come with a variety of formats. Most times you can find the recipient email somewhere inside the delivery status notification mail. But this does not work always since the recipients address might have been rewritten on the way.

To work around this problem one might use a unique sender address for each recipient address, i.e. something like `bounce-foo-at-example.com@yourdomain`. Of course you need then be able to collect all mails sent to `bounce-*@yourdomain`. See also [Sender Rewriting Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme).